# How to get the ID of a clicked HyperLink in it's event handler in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to get the ID of a clicked HyperLink in it's event handler in Javascript?

Comment: The event object should have a `target` property or something similar, depending on if you're using a framework (and I believe IE does not provide the object to you directly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this worked!
this.event.srcElement.id

Comment: Again, I'd love to see your code to know why this is fine, but accessing `this.id` fails.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of the event handling function, `this` is the element that was actually clicked. So accessing `this.id` is what you need.

Comment: Apparently `this.id` wasn't enough characters to allow me to answer in time and I couldn't think of how to add more. +1

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the +1. I had the same problem, but somehow reacted quickly enough this time. :)

Comment: I got "undefined"
And I am using IE, will that be a problem?
Do I need to put somehting in the arguments of the event or so?

Comment: I will need to see your markup and JS in order to tell you what's going on in your specific context.

Comment: This does not work in all cases. see: http://jsfiddle.net/8SMeh/2/  `this` is not the same depending on where its called from.

Comment: @Justin808 - The `javascript:` pseudo-protocol should never be used in an event handler attribute, and it is _HIGHLY_ recommended that you never put JS in the HREF via that pseudo-protocol. If you absolutely must put JS inline on the element (as opposed to assigning behavior programmatically) then use the event handling attributes.

Comment: @JAAulde - I agree, I was just clarifying where it works and where it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
A) <a id="MyID" href="javascript:alert(this.id);">Doesn't Work</a>


B) <a id="MyID" href="#" onclick="alert(this.id);">Works</a>
```

Not sure how to make option A work.

**update** As JAAulde noted in a comment. you really shouldn't use option A.

Answer (score 0):

For IE use event.srcElement.id. For other browsers use event.target.id.